# VIM mode: how to get ex commands to work again in colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Haven't used colab since 2021 - however, with VIM enabled in the editor settings, it seems that I cannot use ex commands anymore, what gives? I believe this was possible before.

For example:
`:s` does not work for search and replacement, instead it enters `INSERT` mode.